# boost locale conversion?

Tags: c++, boost, locale

Could somebody explain how the following [example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/locale/doc/html/conversions_8cpp-example.html) works?

I don't understand how this can work without using boost::locale::to_upper instead of boost::to_upper?

Will boost::to_upper use locale::global? I thought the regular facet/locale stuff couldn't support utf-8 since it works on character basis?

EDIT:

Also is gen("UTF-8") valid?

Furthermore, how does boost::locale work with boost::regex, is boost::32regex still needed to work with utf-8 strings?

Comment: Your link is to the boost::locale introduction index page.

Comment: The link in your question doesn't lead to any example, but the front-page of the Boost.Locale documentation. Please edit your question with either the correct link, or if it's small put the whole program in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two uses of `to_upper()` in this example:

1. `to_upper("grüßen")` which is resolved via the using declaration `using namespace boost::locale`. This is said to produce the correct result, i.e. `GRÜSSEN`.
2. `boost::to_upper_copy(std::string("grüßen"))` which seems to be the version you are referring to as "boost::to_upper". This is said to produce the **incorrect** result, i.e. `GRÜßEN`.

It seems that the root cause of your misunderstanding was that you assumed that "boost::to_upper" does the right things while it is actually meant to do the wrong thing.